# Why is angular view not getting updated here?

Tags: angular

I have a div tag like this:

```
  <div [hidden]="reviewable && !suggestionIsRejected" class="oppia-suggestion-review-message">
    <i [hidden]="reviewMessage === '' || reviewMessage === undefined || reviewMessage === null" class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin"></i>
    <strong>Review message: </strong>{{ reviewMessage }}
  </div>
```

Now, as you can see, I am checking on a `reviewMessage` variable to show a loading indicator if it's empty, otherwise show it's contents. What I see instead is both of them on the screen, i.e. both the loading indicator as well as the message. Why is it happening this way?

[image]

Comment: `reviewMessage === '' || reviewMessage === undefined || reviewMessage === null` -> `false`, so `[hidden] = false`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to do individual value checking, as both `''`, `undefined` and `null` result in **falsy**, just having to negate the variable's value.

Also, your logic is reversed. You will only want to hide when there is some value.

Try:

```html
<div [hidden]="reviewable && !suggestionIsRejected" class="oppia-suggestion-review-message">
  <i [hidden]="reviewMessage" class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin"></i>
  <strong [hidden]="!reviewMessage">Review message: </strong>{{ reviewMessage }}
</div>
```

I don't know how the rest of your logic is, but possibly you would also need to put the `<i [hidden]="reviewMessage" class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin"></i>` outside the div.